# Unity Pro trial watermark still shows after Upgrading to Pro

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, watermark

I have been using the Unity 4 Pro trial version for a couple weeks now. I decided to upgrade to the actual Pro version so I could publish games.

The issue I am having is that even though I have upgraded the version away from trial, (yes, I have put the new serial number in that I was given by Unity and activated it) my games still have the Trial watermark in the bottom right corner.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should probably contact their company, if you're paying for it they have support available.

Comment: Obviously I did that, but waiting on reply and thought that maybe someone had come across same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got an email back from Unity in case other people see this:

"That is because your invoice is unpaid. Once payment has cleared I remove the trial watermark from the software."

Interesting but fair :)